# Сравнение даты POST и MySQL

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Народ, подскажите как правильно установить формат вывода даты при MySQL запросах?

К примеру, месяц передается через POST в формате 1-12, а в таблице MySQL datatime записывает в формате 01-12:

```
$new_q = $db->query("select * from user_ts where 
                     name='". $login ."' and
                     DATE_FORMAT(registered,'%Y')='". $year ."' and
                     DATE_FORMAT(registered,'%m')='". $now_month ."' LIMIT 1"
                   )->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Такой запрос не прокатывает, как я понял, из-за того, что форматы месяца расходятся.

Можно ли в MySQL изменить формат записи или как то конвертировать формат даты при MySQL запросе?

Спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо, нашел ответ, вывод месяца в формате 1-12 задается через %c а не %n

Answer (score 2):

Отправляйте через Post не число 1-12, а строку '01-12'.